# dubts about security with passwords in database

Tags: database, security, passwords

I have read this article: http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

and in the section where to hash the password, it says that is better to hash the password in the server, because if someone stole the hash database can access to the user account without the need of the password.

But if someone can stole the hash database, he can access to the whole database, is correct? if this is correct, he can access to all the data, no only of the user information. So why could he want only part of the information?

Comment: It's not that passwords are all that an attacker might care about -- but passwords, unlike other data, can be protected by providing it in a comparison-only form (such as a one-way hash) rather than raw; whereas with most other fields, they need to be read back, not only compared. Thus, passwords can be protected in ways that other content cannot.

Comment: You can accepts and promote my answer if it answers your question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An attacker generally tries to steal database to be able to access to an application.
Of course, if a database contains a sensitive information (like credit card numbers) he do not need to access to the application if he stole the database.
(The PCI DSS standard explains how to store the credit cards information)

If he found a plain text password – he will be able to access an application without any problem. 
But if a database contains the hashed value the attacker need to found a plain text value that corresponds to the hashed value.
If you use weak hash algorithms like MD5 or SHA1 the attacker can easier to fine the plain text value.

For better protection it is recommended to use strong hash algorithms like SHA128 or SHA 256.
In addition, it is strongly recommend to use a different salt value for each user.
(Tip: to store the value in the column that not called salt, for example userhint)

General comment: In security you should protect as much as possible.
You protect your application against SQL injection to prevent stealing of a database https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet
You hash / encrypt sensitive in case your database is stolen: data https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A6-Sensitive_Data_Exposure

Comment: Yes, but I think that the basic function of the applications is to be a friendly way to access to the database. So if someone can bypass the need to log in the application because can access to the database, why someone who is trying to stole information would want to use the application?

Comment: For example, an online store application. In this case if an attacker access to the database - he  will not be able to do a lot. But if he will be able to login and to order a staff on behalf of a victim to his address - it is not good. Please comment if you need additional explanation.